# ANTLR4 grammar doesn't recognize declaration

Tags: regex, antlr, grammar, antlr4

I have a problem with my ANTLR grammar.

In SQL there are declaration types like `UNSIGNED INT` or `UNSIGNED BIGINT`. If I run my grammar with ANTLRWorks in Testrig the parser has a problem with the `UNSIGNED`.

This is my grammar part for `declare_type`

```
declare_type
    : BIT
    | BOOLEAN
    | CHAR ('(' expression ')')?
    | CHARACTER ('(' expression ')')?
    ...
```

Attempt 1:

```
    ...
    | UNSIGNED? INT
    | UNSIGNED? BIGINT
    ;
```

Attempt 2:

```
    ...
    | INT
    | BIGINT
    | UNSIGNED INT
    | UNSIGNED BIGINT
    ;
```

Attempt 3:

```
    ...
    | INT
    | BIGINT
    | unsigned_separable_element
    ;

unsigned_separable_element
    : UNSIGNED INT 
    | UNSIGNED BIGINT
    ;
```

I hope you guys know what I my problem is, thanks.

EDITED:
I uploaded the full grammar to [GitHub](https://github.com/xnappy/SybaseIQParser/blob/master/tsql.g4)

Example: `DECLARE value UNSIGNED INT;` doesn't work because the grammar doesn't recognize `UNSIGNED`

If I use only `INT` then it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through the grammar and the problem is not poetic at all. Just a typo in the UNSIGNED lexer rule... It was " U N S I G N D" - missing E

Comment: **buried in shame** I really tried everything - thanks thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could you specify what kind of a problem do you have? Or at least post whole grammar file? The way lexer rules are specified is important in solving a lot of problems in ANTLR. Thanks.

Comment: I created a repo with the grammar in github because those 1,6k long grammar is to long for stackoverflow: [GitHub](https://github.com/xnappy/SybaseIQParser/blob/master/tsql.g4) --- my problem appears with an easy declare statement `DECLARE varName UNSIGNED INT;`  -- thanks